# Using multiple delimiters with scanner - Java

Tags: java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm trying to use both tabs and newlines as delimiters to read from a .txt file. What I have at the moment is:

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("propertys.txt"));

fileScanner.useDelimiter("[\\t\\n]");
```

I've tried:

```
fileScanner.useDelimiter("\\t|\\n");
```

and

```
fileScanner.useDelimiter("[\\t|\\n]");
```

I've got no idea what's going wrong, I've searched around a lot and it looks like one of those should be working. Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

fileScanner.useDelimiter("\t|\n"); 
should work.

If you have two slashes "\n" the first acts as an escape and it won't work right.

Answer (score 0):

For the regular expression used as a parameter in useDelimiter method, you should use newline as `\n` instead of `\\n` and tab as `\t` instead of `\\t`. From Java Pattern class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

A part from that, I think you should define you regular expression like, for example, this:

```
fileScanner.useDelimiter("\\s*[\t\n]\\s*");
```

to limit strings (`\\s`) between newline or tab characters.

Comment: But since it's reading from a txt file I thought I needed the extra slash? Either way it still didn't work, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ahh still not working, I think I'm just going to approach it from a different angle, thanks for the help though.

Comment: Edited again with something else I found. I hope this time is the good one :)

Comment: God I'm an idiot, I had an extra newline at the end of the file which was making it throw an exception. Thanks again for the help, all sorted now :)

Comment: You're welcome and also welcome to Stack Overflow. I would advise you to give a positive punctuation and/or accept an answer given to you if you consider it useful (especially for punctuation) or the correct one (especially for accept). Accepting an answer will allow you to get your first Badge (http://stackoverflow.com/badges), in this case the Scholar one. Giving an up vote (i.e. positive punctuation) will also allow you to earn a Badge, in that case, the Supporter one. Of course, these are just suggestions ;)